# How to declare a class copy inside the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application that runs every minute to analyze the products of a store, to start I created an array with 5 stores, each store has its sales and each sale has its products. So to start the analysis, I created a forEach that runs through all the stores, because I want the 5 to be executed in parallel, inside that forEach I execute a for sales, inside that I declare some modules and call the methods going on sale as parameter, within these modules I execute another for the products of the sale and this loop instantiates other modules and classes, when I execute this the first and/or second time it works normally, after several iterations begin to bugar, for example, in the sale 123 of store 1, it uses the properties that store 2 sales 231 used.

I do not know if you could understand this problem, but it's a little confusing to explain, basically I wanted each loop iteration to use a copy of the module/class without changing the properties of other iterations, if I declare the Sales class in iteration 1 and also declare the same class in iteration 2, this iteration cannot receive the properties of iteration 1. In short, I want to instantiate a single class/module for each iteration without them changing the properties of each other.

This was my attempt using an array of objects to store instances of classes/modules:

**main.js**

```
const analysis = require('./modules/analysis');
const check = require('./modules/check');
const api = require('../wrappers/api');

stores.forEach(async function(store) {
    let sales = [];
    await api.getSales(store.id).then((response) => {
      sales = response.result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      logger.error(error);
    });

    let analysisModule = {};
    let checkModules = {};

    for(const sale of sales){
         // Analysis
         analysisModule[sale.id] = Object.assign({}, analysis);
         await analysisModule[sale.id].run(sale);
         delete analysisModule[sale.id];

         // Check
         checkModules[sale.id] = Object.assign({}, check);
         await checkModules[sale.id].run(sale);
         delete checkModules[sale.id];
    }
});
```

**check.js**

```
const Stock = require('./stock');
const Provider = require('./provider');
const api = require('../wrappers/api');
const common = require('./common');

const check = {
    run: async function(sale) {
        var self = this;
        let items = await api.getItems(sale.id, 1);
        if (!items.success && items.result.lenght == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        let providerClass = {};
        let stockClass = {};

        for (const item of items.result) {

            // Here is problem
            providerClass[item.id] = await new Provider(sale, item);
            let allowed = await providerClass[item.id].check();
            if (!allowed) {
                continue;
            }

            // Here is problem
            stockClass[item.id] = new Stock(sale, item);
            let checked = await stockClass[item.id].check();
            if (checked) {
               continue;
            }

            delete providerClass[item.id];
            delete stockClass[item.id];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this? `let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))`

Comment: But can I use the methods of the class? The problem is that I have a constructor and I need to pass the parameters on it, how would it look?

Comment: `for (item of items.result) {` is missing a `const`/`let`/`var` declaration. Always use strict mode to catch such mistakes!

Comment: Btw, you should just use `const sales = (await api.getSales(store.id)).result;`. No `then`.

Comment: Okay, this is not the problem, the problem is that it does not declare a single class for each iteration, if I modify a class that was declared in iteration 2, the class declared in iteration 1 will also have its properties modified, understood?

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your question, mostly because you talk about the problem in abstract terms, unconnected to the code. It seems like there's likely more code here than needs to be. Cut out lines of code until the problem goes away, then add back in the code you just deleted. See [mcve] for more.